# Change The Reference Frame of Face Tracking Result from Kinect SDK

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have been developing a multi-kinect face tracking system, and I wonder that how can I change the reference frame of face tracking result?

I tried to compute rotation matrix from face rotation angles(extracted by Kinect SDK) using XYZ  convention,make a translation vector using face position vector, and combine this transformation
matrix with the transformation matrix from this kinect to global frame. Here is the formula:

```
   T = T_local_to_global*T_face
```

And finally transform the combined T back to rotation angles using method like

https://truesculpt.googlecode.com/hg-history/38000e9dfece971460473d5788c235fbbe82f31b/Doc/rotation_matrix_to_euler.pdf

However, the result is somehow wrong. The rotation angle relative to Z axis sometimes flips.Did I made a mistake somewhere? Appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

---

update:

I found that different conventions of rotation matrix gives different result.
What is the convention of the rotation angle given by Kinect SDK? 
Or the angles are actually not euler angle?

So confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse-engineer the convention used by the Face Tracking API by passing test values of `rotationXYZ` into `IFTModel::Get3DShape()`. I believe its order of angles is to rotate around Z first, then Y, then X. In other words, R = R_x R_y R_z as matrices.

Note that by contrast, the PDF you linked to uses the convention R = R_z R_y R_x, which means to rotate around X first, then Y, then Z.